# Protractor How to click on a blank place

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

We are using Protractor to test an Angular JS project.
There is one page I need to click on a blank place (any blank place) to trigger the auto save after filled in all the required fields.

But I don't know how. I tried to find a useless image or click back on a text box. It cannot work.

Stacktrace:

> UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (975, 357). Other element would receive the click: ...*

Any comments will be helpful, thanks very much.

Comment: Maybe 
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.LEFT).perform();

Answer (score 6):

One option would be to find a particular element and *click with an offset*:

```
var elm = element(by.css('.material-dialog-container'));
browser.actions()
    .mouseMove(elm, -20, -20)
    .click()
    .perform();
```

Where the offset is counted from the top left corner of the element.

Comment: Thank you, you gave me a good way to think. And code should be: `browser.actions().mouseMove(elm, {x: 500, y: 500}).click().perform();`

Answer (score 1):

in such cases you can click on `document.body`

if you are testing a directive you need to append it to the body first.

```
element = angular.element('<your-directive></your-directive>');
compile(element)(scope).appendTo(document.body);
```